# Is it possible to copy files between 2 servers using different credentials in Powershell 2? also different domains

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

What's the easiest way to copy many folders between 2 servers with different credentials having the servers in different domains.
As far as I know, the `-credentials` parameter came up in `Powershell 3.0`,
so how to achieve it using `Powershell 2`?
If possible I want to keep it easy using the `copy-item` cmdlet.
I already created the function to select my folder, but I am unable to copy them through network.

Comment: The easiest way is to map a network drive and use `robocopy` to transfer the folders.

Comment: yes but I only need to copy some of the folders which were modified later than X. Isnt there a good powershell solution ?

Comment: `robocopy` does have a `/maxage` parameter. And of course you can also copy folders to mapped network drives with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use     Copy-Item and     -Credential not     -Credentials